# Functions with a zero derivative form an ideal of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

Denote $Z \subset C^\infty(X)$ the set of functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has a zero derivative at $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $Z$ is an ideal of a ring $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I showed $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a ring under pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication. Also $Z$ is a subgroup of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

a. I do not know what it means for $f$ to have a zero derivative at $p$ since $f$ is a function of $n$-variables. Wrt what variable should I differentiate? I assumed that the derivative of $f$ at $p$ is
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p) + ... +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(p)$.

For simplicity assume $n=1$. When taking $f \in Z, g \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^1)$, then the derivative of $f.g$ at $p$ is $(f.g)'(p)=f'(p).g(p)+f(p).g'(p)=f(p).g'(p)$ which is not necessarily zero, hence $f.g$ does not need to be in $Z$, so $Z$ is not an ideal.

b. Is my reasoning correct, should I have taken different ring operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring operations you picked are the standard ring operations for ring-valued functions and are always understood in those cases unless specified otherwise, so that's all fine.

The derivative in here is a vector with $n$ components. So to say tha tthe derivative is $0$ means that *all* partial derivateives are zero. Your counterexample for $n=1$ is correct though. Maybe the problem wanted to ask for $f(p)=0$ and $Df(p)=0$?